# Track file import into database

Tags: java

I need to test file import status using this Java code:

```
    @EventListener
    public void handleContextStart(ContextRefreshedEvent eventd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Handling context started event.!!!");

        System.out.println("Running file verifier");
        System.out.println("monitoring folder " + folderPath);

        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path path = Paths.get(folderPath);
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
                if(event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE)){
                    Instant start = Instant.now();

                    AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(true);

                    while(flag.get()) {
                        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {

                            List<EntityImportRequestsTable> list = entityImportRequestsService.findAll();
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                            for(EntityImportRequestsTable item : list){
                                map.put(item.getRequestXmlSourceFile(), item.getStatusCode());
                            }

                            map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());

                                // compare file name from list and file name from the delete event by file name
                                if(entry.getKey().contains(event.context().toString())){
                                    // exit the monitoring while loop
                                    flag.set(false);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                    Instant end = Instant.now();
                    System.out.println(Duration.between(start,end));

                    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Duration.between(start,end).getSeconds());
                    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(Duration.between(start,end).getSeconds());

                    System.out.format("Execution time %d minutes %d seconds", minutes, seconds);


                }

            }
            key.reset();
        }

        watchService.close();
    }
```

When file is processed  from the tested app the file is deleted and imported into database. If the file import is successfully imported the status is completed.

When I run the above program noting happens. Do you know how I can properly track the file import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop over the events is flawed as it will skip over events because you have double calls to `watchService.take()`. The second call may block, and if it works the events will be skipped so the inner loop may never match up a delete or exit correctly. Remove the second `take()`:

```
while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
   ... 
   while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
   ...
```

Here is an example of logic for setting up the WatchService, you should try with `System.out.println()` to understand how it works:

```
Path watchDir = Path.of("whatever");
try (WatchService service = watchDir.getFileSystem().newWatchService()) {

    // Add whatever StandardWatchEventKinds events you need
    WatchKey wk = watchDir.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE /*, ENTRY_CREATE ENTRY_DELETE ... ETC */);
    // Insert your own loop termination condition here:
    while (running) {
        WatchKey key = service.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (key == null) {
            continue;
        }

        for (var event : key.pollEvents())  {
            Path evPath  = (Path) event.context();
            Path absPath = ((Path) key.watchable()).resolve(evPath);
            Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

            System.out.println("Kind=" + kind + " Path=" + evPath+" AbsPath=" + absPath);
            // Check each event to see if your termination condition is met
        }

        key.reset();
    }
}
```

Running the above should give you an idea of what `WatchService` provides, and you can fill in your own logic into `pollEvents()` loop to handle each delete notification:

```
 // Check each event to see if your termination condition is met
 if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE) {
     if (absPath is one of the files you want) {
         Mark as received + print timings
         running = (number of remaining files you want > 0);
     }
 }
```

You may find it easier to refactor the watch service part as a separate component so that it collates events and delivers a set of changes to a listener - see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65223686/java-watchservice-perform-action-on-event-using-threads/65251819#65251819).

If your listener/handler inside the loop can take some time, run watch service and handler in separate threads so that the event loop keeps up with watch event publishing, and don't use `sleep` as that may cause overflow events because your listener/handler is too slow.

Comment: One more request. Can you show me how I can make the code if possible much more simple?

Comment: The example I linked can be set up in test program, you can plug in your own code with `w.setListener(your::callback);` and it can call `w.shutdown()` when task is complete.

Comment: Can you paste a complete code example please?

Comment: For `watchDir` what  I need to use?

Comment: Set `Path watchDir` to any folder you want to watch then make some changes there and observe.

Comment: What is `kinds`?

Comment: Same as you've used in you own code, though you didn't need to add `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY` if wanting delete events only.

Comment: Can you extend please the code to track the time for some event? In my case as you can see track file delete and DB status update to completed.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention time tracking nor DB updating, and StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. However, I'll append a suggestion to the answer which hopefully points you in the right direction.