# CSV File Parsing Issue - csvParser.iterator().next()

Tags: java, watchservice

Here is the Java code for reading and parsing a CSV file.

```
String filePath = dir.resolve(filename).toString();
try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
     CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
         .withHeader(...))) {

    // Check if there is a next element before calling next()
    if (csvParser.iterator().hasNext()) {
        csvParser.iterator().next();
        
        for (CSVRecord record : csvParser) {
        ...
        }
        ...
    } else {
        // Handle the case where there are no more CSV records available
        log.warn("No more CSV records available");
    }
}
```

The above code will have different outcomes for the same CSV file. That is the condition (csvParser.iterator().hasNext() will return different values between true and false. I just did a test for the same CSV file and the first two times it goes to the line _"No more CSV records available" (I removed the file when this case occurred) and the data in the CSV file is loaded on the third attempt. To my eyes, I can't find any issues in the CSV file.

I've ruled out issues related to file content, format, and headers, there could be other factors contributing to this inconsistency. The additional points I can't consider to be the cause:

Resource Handling: Ensure that the csvParser and fileReader are properly managed and not subject to unexpected closures or resource issues. Double-check for any resource-related exceptions that might affect the behavior of the CSVParser.

Concurrency: If multiple threads or processes are accessing the same file concurrently, it can lead to unpredictable results. Ensure that you have proper synchronization in place to avoid concurrent access issues.

Library Version: Check if you are using an older or less stable version of the CSV parsing library. Updating to a more recent version or switching to a different library might help resolve the issue if it's a library-specific bug.

JVM or Environment Issues: In rare cases, JVM or environment-specific issues could lead to inconsistent behavior. Make sure your JVM and environment are up to date and correctly configured.

External Factors: Consider other factors that might be affecting the behavior, such as system load, file system issues, or other external factors that can impact file access and I/O operations.

I don't know whether this issue relates to how the file is read or not. I use the WatchService to get a CSV file

```java
try {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/my_file";
    Path dir = Paths.get(path);
    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    log.warn("Monitoring directory: " + dir);

    while (true) {
        WatchKey key = watcher.take();
        boolean oneLoop = processWatchKeyEvents(key, dir);
        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            break;
        }
        if (oneLoop) {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("Error in monitoring directory: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

What is a possible cause of this issue?

Comment: Are you reading the file _immediately_ after receiving a create event? If you are, what happens if you add a delay before reading the file (possibly where the delay restarts if you receive a modify event before the delay elapsed, assuming you register for `ENTRY_MODIFY` as well).

Comment: Yes, a CSV file is processed once it is detected in the directory. There isn't ENTRY_MODIFY in the code. So, what you said is that CSVParser may not get any data from the file right after it is created,

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that you are reading the file before anything has actually been written to it. Or at least before the written data becomes visible to other applications. And that's why I asked if your code works if you add a delay. Also, I know there's no `ENTRY_MODIFY` in your code; didn't say there was. I was suggesting that you may want to register for those events as well, so that you can restart the delay when you receive a modify event. But only if that's important to your use case.

Comment: Not sure I follow. The code reads and parses the data in a CSV file. It is straightforward. If I pause the code after creating a CSVParser, the whole procedure will be paused, I guess. If ENTRY_MODIFY means to detect the same file in the directory for a second time, the event isn't in the use case. One CSV file only can be dropped in the directory once. I hope I understand your suggestion correctly.

Comment: Also, I need to mention that I only observed the issue with one CSV file, but not the other file of two files for the test.

Comment: You receive an `ENTRY_CREATE` event and then immediately open the file for reading. I'm suggesting that you aren't giving enough time for whatever application created the file to actually write any data to said file. If you are _moving_ an existing file, then what I'm suggesting may not apply to your situation, but only if the move is atomic.

Comment: Note that my comments are only a hypothesis regarding what may be going wrong with your code. It's possible you are running into a different issue. Or maybe you're running into the timing issue I've described in addition to another issue.

Comment: *if (csvParser.iterator().hasNext())* surely should be `while` ..?

Comment: @g00se the condition was added to prevent an exception we are discussing.

Comment: @Slaw I forgot to provide a detail on the test I mentioned.  I placed the CSV file in the directory. After the code didn't work as expected, I removed the file. The same for the second time. Without this detail, you likely think the ENTRY_MODIFY event should be created.

Comment: I think you are focusing too much on my mention of `ENTRY_MODIFY`, which was essentially a side point. The important part is that you delay before reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

It is unwise to handle watch service events immediately especially as the `WatchService` would normally provide DELETE+CREATE+N x MODIFY events for same file operation. As you are ignoring MODIFY you won't know when it is safe(ish) to access your CSV.

You will be better off collating events and handling in separate process queue once the watch service is quiet, and use combination of poll+take. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65223686/java-watchservice-perform-action-on-event-using-threads/65251819#65251819) which should provide a better trigger point for you to begin operations on the CSV. In the example `setListener` just prints the activity, replace with your own handler for CSV.